# jQuery select SVG anchor elements inside <object> tag

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, svg, anchor

I am having quite a bit of trouble using the anchor elements built into my SVG (displayed as an `<object>`). I am trying to target the anchor elements within my Object with jQuery to toggle its respective piece of content when clicked.

If you take a look at my example, I have 3 links built into my SVG (they are a lighter shade of green than the others). I used InkScape to create my SVG image, and on the light green areas that are linked are just shapes with the href attribute equal to "#operable-shades", "#gutters-downspouts", and "#gable-pediments" respectively.

With my SVG displaying nicely on my page (using an `<object>` tag), when hovering over the links I have created I get the original object data URL with my specified anchor appended to the end of it (ex. 'https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/GHB_Interface-v0.1.svg#gable-pediments') when I would expect it to be 'https://example.com/#gable-pediments'.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.ghb_toggle').hide()
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(event) {
        var target = $(this).attr('href');
        $(target).toggle();
    });
});
</script>
```

```css
.ghb_toggle {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/test.svg" width="500" height="400"></object>

<div id="gable-pediments" class="ghb_toggle">
  <p>Content 1</p>
</div>

<div id="gutters-downspouts" class="ghb_toggle">
  <p>Content 2</p>
</div>

<div id="operable-shades" class="ghb_toggle">
  <p>Content 3</p>
</div>
```

How can I modify my jQuery to be able to successfully interact with my anchor elements inside my `<object>` to hide/show a respective piece of content with a unique identifier?

Comment: I don't think you can select svg tags when imported via an object element. Just like you can't when an image is used.

Comment: You can do it but only if the contents of the <object> tag are the same domain as the page. In the example case in the question, they aren't.

Comment: And unfortunately the image itself is enormous so I can't even turn it into a data URL to construct an answer out of it so we still need a [mcve] here i.e. something that uses a small test SVG file.

Comment: @RobertLongson I have learnt something today. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To target the content of an svg document loaded inside an `<object>`, or `<iframe>`, you need to pass the correct Document context to jQuery: the one you can access from the `.contentDocument` property of the embedding element.

Note that this requires that the svg document has been loaded in a same-origin way, which is not possible in StackSnippets' null origined frames, so here is a [live plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/PaGdoTwLj4ER5lvK?open=lib%2Fscript.js).

```js
$( "object" ).on( "load", (evt) => {
  const svg_doc = this.contentDocument;
  $( "a[href]", svg_doc ) // second argument is context
    .on( 'click', (evt) => {
      // add your listener here
    } );
};
```

Also note that in your svg you have `xlink:href` attributes being defined, not just `href`, so your jQuery selector should be `'a[xlink\\:href^="#"]'`

---

But if your goal is to set the anchors in you svg relative to an other base URL than the one the document is loaded from, then you don't need all this, you can simply insert an HTML `<base>` element at the beginning of your svg document and all the relative URLs will use it.
See live demo as a [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/2iJt6JbRDUP9yY42?open=lib%2Fscript.js) and a more complicated snippet:

```js
// To be able to embed it in a StackSnippet (directly in this answer),
// we need to generate the file in memory from JS
// you don't need it
const svg_content = `
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 50 50" width="300" >
  <!-- we must declare it in the HTML namespace -->
  <base xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" href="https://google.com" />
  <a href="#foo-bar">
    <rect fill="green" x="10" y="10" width="30" height="30" />
  </a>
</svg>
`;
const svg_blob = new Blob( [ svg_content ], { type: "image/svg+xml" } );
const svg_url = URL.createObjectURL( svg_blob );
document.querySelector( "object" ).data = svg_url;
```

```html
<object></object>
```

Comment: You're the man! Through some testing I found that I am indeed able to target my anchor elements inside my SVG! Now I must figure out how to handle toggling the content. I was using `var target = $(this).attr('xlink\\:href');` and then `$(target).toggle();` but I cannot seem to get anything of the sort to actually toggle the `<div>` elements with unique identifiers.

Comment: In your event handler you can access the main document normally.