# Add target to SVG a tag

Tags: php, jquery, svg

I am trying to add `target="_blank"` to my SVG `<a/>` tag but I can't figure out why my code isn't working.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function loadedSVG() {
        $('#svg1 a').attr('target', '_blank');
    }
</script>
<object id="svg1" data="SVG_File.svg" type="image/svg+xml" onload='loadedSVG()'>
    <a href="http://www.yahoo.com/">yahoo</a>
</object>
```

The code works on the Yahoo link but not on hrefs within the SVG file, anybody have any idee how I can fix this?

Comment: The SVG file is a separate document. You'd need to run a script within that file or extract the object's document and update everything that way.

Comment: Is there some way I can include a script when i create the SVG <object>?

Comment: That's the second method I outlined.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the link must be outer of object tag

```js
function loadedSVG() {
  $('#container a').attr('target', '_blank');
}
```

```css
#container{
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

a{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

#svg1{
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <a href="http://www.yahoo.com/">yahoo</a>
    <object id="svg1" data="https://la-cascade.io/content/images/2015/06/kiwi.svg" type="image/svg+xml" onload='loadedSVG()'>
    </object>    
</div>
```

Regards

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. The script adds the target='blank' to the yahoo link but my problem is that it doesn't do the same for the hrefs within the SVG file.

Comment: @Unskilled oh sorry. Maybe this link could help you. There is an example: [link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64452584/jquery-select-svg-anchor-elements-inside-object-tag[/link]

Answer (score 0):

You should put `object` tag in `a` tag

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function loadedSVG() {
        $('#svg1 a').attr('target', '_blank');
    }
</script>
<a href="http://www.yahoo.com/">
   <object id="svg1" data="SVG_File.svg" type="image/svg+xml" onload='loadedSVG()'>
     yahoo
   </object>
</a>
```

hope that's help